# How do I display a 12X12 grid of 48X48 Pixel Images on a window in java

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine

I want to make my own engine, but in order to do that I want to fully understand how to do this. All I need is to know how I can display the grid using a nil layout manager. Reason for the nil manager is because in order to move the map I need to put an image off screen and then scroll everything into view.

If there is an easier way to do this that doesn't involve using a pre-made engine, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem. I won't write out all of the detailed code for you, but here's the basic idea.

1. Load up your image into a BufferedImage called. See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html.
2. Make a subclass of `JPanel` called `MapPanel`
3. Override the
   [paintComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method of `MapPanel` like this:

   `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g.create();
       graphics.drawImage(img /*This is what you loaded in Step 1*/, null, 0, 0);
    }`

   This will just paint the image onto a panel.
4. Now go back to your GUI code and create a main `JPanel` with a null layout manager, like you said.
5. Make a plain 12x12 2 dimensional array of `MapPanels`
6. Loop through this array using something like this:

   `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            array[i][j] = new MapPanel();
            array[i][j].setBounds(12 * i, 12 * j, 48, 48);
        }
    }`
7. Now add all of those MapPanels to your main null-layout `JPanel`. Make a `JFrame` and set your main `JPanel` as the content pane.
8. You're done!

Hope this helped! :) If you don't understand something in this, feel free to ask Google before you ask here.

#### Edit:

As @drewmoore said, absolute positioning is tedious. If you want to use `GridLayout` and Timing Framework, just set your main `JPanel` layout to `GridLayout` and remove the `array[i][j].setBounds(12 * i, 12 * j, 48, 48);` part from Step 6. After that, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Look, I've been down the [absolute positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) road in AWT/Swing. It works, and you can do just about anything you want with it,  but... a) you're going to need to learn a bit (start with the link above); and b) be ready to pull some hair out - you don't realize how much the layout managers do until you go without them.

It sounds like you have a textbook use-case for a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), except you need to animate that layout onto the screen. If that's the case, the "easier way" is most certainly *not* to go absolute-positioning all the way. Use a `GridLayout` to lay out your GUI in one container, and then place that container into an absolutely-positioned container and use a `SwingTimer` to animate *that* onto the screen, rather than positioning the whole thing absolutely. Better yet, use [Timing Framework](https://www.java.net/project/timingframework) or another library built for precisely this purpose.